# I am able to convert pre-trained models(pfe.onnx and rpn.onnx) into tensorrt. But I am not able to convert our models into tensorrt

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ONNX IR version: 0.0.4
Opset version: 9
Producer name: pytorch
Producer version: 1.1
Domain:
Model version: 0
Doc string: While parsing node number 16 [Squeeze -> “175”]: ERROR: /home/erisuser/p4sw/sw/gpgpu/MachineLearning/DIT/release/5.0/parsers/onnxOpenSource/builtin_op_importers.cpp:1570 In function importSqueeze: [8] Assertion failed: axis != BATCH_DIM ERROR: failed to parse onnx file  Please address the issue. Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328609/i-am-able-to-convert-pre-trained-models(pfe.onnx-and-rpn.onnx)-into-tensorrt.-but-i-am-not-able-to-convert-our-models-into-tensorrt./) by [Siva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44063/siva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mackou](https://answers.ros.org/users/46580/mackou/) on 2019-11-21**:
@Siva, did you manage to find a solution to your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you for your question.
Unfortunately, if you want to use your own model, it is the out of the scope of Autoware.

You can ask a question regarding TensorRT here.
https://www.nvidia.com/object/support.html

Here for pytorch questions.
https://discuss.pytorch.org/

---

Originally posted by [kosuke_murakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/41340/kosuke_murakami/) with karma: 81 on 2019-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44063/siva/) on 2019-07-16**:
Thanks for the reply. May I know which version of Pytorch you used to convert to onnx models and tensorrt version?

**Comment by [kosuke_murakami](https://answers.ros.org/users/41340/kosuke_murakami/) on 2019-07-16**:
Please check the readme.md for TensorRT version.
https://gitlab.com/kosuke_m/core_perception/tree/master/lidar_point_pillars

Any version of pytorch which can convert to onnx model should be fine.

**Comment by [Siva](https://answers.ros.org/users/44063/siva/) on 2019-07-16**:
Got it,

I am using Pytorch 1.1,tensorrt 5.0(as you mentioned in readme), ONNX IR version:0.0.4, Opset version:9 and converted to onnx. Now i can able to convert rpn.onnx to rpn.trt but i am not able to convert pfe.onnx to pfe.trt.

The error is like below:

While parsing node number 16 [Squeeze -> “175”]: ERROR: /home/erisuser/p4sw/sw/gpgpu/MachineLearning/DIT/release/5.0/parsers/onnxOpenSource/builtin_op_importers.cpp:1570 In function importSqueeze: [8] Assertion failed: axis != BATCH_DIM ERROR: failed to parse onnx file